# Find a user by their real name in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This script is for reseting passwords on AD users if they lost it and need to make a new one. But let's say we dont know the username only their real name, so we want to search for the username and insert it to `$Username`.

```
function Reset_Password_Account () {
    $Username = Read-Host "Enter your username" 
    Write-Host "Changing Password for account" $Username

    $Newpassword = Read-Host "Enter Temporary Password" -AsSecureString
    Write-Host "Running Script..."

    Set-ADAccountPassword $Username -NewPassword $Newpassword
    Write-Host "Temporary password set"

    Set-ADUser $Username -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
    Write-Host "You can now change password on login"

    # Stop powershell from exiting after script is run
    Read-Host "Press enter to exit"
}

$Readhost = Read-Host "To run script: Enter y 
To decline script: Enter n and exit PowerShell 
Press Enter to accept your input. ( y / n )" 
switch ($ReadHost) {
    Y {Reset_Password_Account}
    N {exit}
```

Comment: You're looking for [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser).

Comment: [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx) will certainly help you here: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=Jim Smith)"`

Comment: Ahh thank you my brother

Comment: @JamesC. You should make that an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx), it searches a range if AD Attributes (list in link) and finds any matches.

The example query below would return both `Jimmy Smith` and `Jim Smith-Williams`

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=Jim Smith)"
```

It will search for all objects where any of the naming attributes start with the string `"jim smith*"`, plus all objects where `(givenName=jim*)` and `(sn=smith*)`, plus objects where `(givenName=smith*)` and `(sn=jim*)`.